# System message from backend Quickblox

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to send a System message from backend to an user using the example in the website and it just does not work. The thing is that I am updating the data of many dialogs (Group dialogs - type == 2) from backend and I want to notify (with a system message) to all the users in those dialogs that the data changes; but the message is not received in the mobile clients.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the documentation for it :

[System_Notifications](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#System_Notifications)

All System Notifications should Contains **extraParams.moduleIdentifier=SystemNotifications ** and **type=headline**.